# Elements to spread equally with space over parent width - Angular Flexlayout responsive

Tags: html, css, angular, flexbox, angular-flex-layout

I want to render 3 div squares: **div-left**, **div-middle**, and **div-right** (each of width 300px) to be spread across the width of the parent div **main-section** which should be 1300px if screen>1300px and to shrink if the screen<1300px.

The 3 squares should be positioned as follows: starting with 0px (the left side of **div-left**) until 1300px (the right side of **div-right**) and with equal spaces between the squares.

**main-section** is enclosed in the parent div **full-width-section** which takes the full width of the screen so that it is not empty in case the screen>1300px;

The idea is I don't want the **main-section** to be larger than 1300px when the screen>1300px but to shrink if the screen<1300px. By using flex layout I wanted the 3 squares to be separated equally when the screen shrinks, making it responsive.

Also **main-section** should be in the center of **full-width-section** and take 1300px if screen>1300px.

At this moment I managed to position **main-section** in the center but does not take 1300px if screen>1300px, it only takes the sum of the square widths.

HTML (divs colored for easier view):

```
<div class="full-width-section" fxLayout fxLayoutAlign="space-evenly stretch">
  <div class="main-section" fxLayout fxLayoutAlign="space-between center">
    <div class="div-left" style="background: #df1313;width: 300px; height: 300px;"></div>
    <div class="div-middle" style="background: #4826df;width: 300px; height: 300px;"></div>
    <div class="div-right" style="background: #25ca57;width: 300px; height: 300px;"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.full-width-section {
    width: 100%;
    background: #4bd0f1;
}

.main-section {
    max-width: 1300px;
    background: #e2d959;
}
```

[link to demo.](https://stackblitz.com/github//mmm2306/flexbox-app)
I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you remove the flex layout directives from the outer wrapper, then you should get the desired behavior. I have modified your example, it can be found [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-kunt9z)

Comment: I tried this and it fixes partially, the space are there but the main-section is not centered in full-width-section. in your example is at the start of full-width-section

Comment: Oh, sorry, I missed that requirement. I have updated the forked snipped by adding a good ol' margin: 0 auto, in order to center the main-section. Please check if that works for you.